# Bug displaying a div element when a user clicks on a button

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm writing a webpage and I need to display a div with some content when a user clicks on a button.
I've written the code below and I don't understand why it doesn't work.
Does someone know why ?

My code :

```
  <html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso 8859-1" />

    <script type="text/javascript">

    function traverse(){
        output.innerHTML+='Test'; // Nothing happens !
    }

          function check() {
            var keywords = document.getElementById('text').value.split(" ");

            for (var i=0; i < keywords.length; ++i) {
                traverse_tree()    
            }
          }


    </script>


  </head>
  <body onload ="init()">
        <input id="text" type="text" size="60" value="Type your keywords here" />
        <input type="button" value="Display the text 'Test'" onclick="check();" />      

        <div id="output">
        </div>

  </body>
  </html>
```

thanks,

Bruno

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps because the function is called `traverse()` and you're calling `traverse_tree()`?

Comment: Don't be. I've done similar things many times. Such an easy mistake to make.

Answer (score 0):

Also, in your method `traverse`, you should get the element using `document.getElementById('output')`, instead of using a (undefined) variable `output`:

i.e:

```
function traverse(){
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML+='Test'; 
}
```

You could also speed this up by caching the node (to avoid calling getElementById each time the button is clicked):

```
// Create a closure by wrapping the cached node in a self-executing
// function to avoid polluting the global namespace
var traverse = (function (nodeId) {

  // Cache the node to be updated here
  var node = document.getElementById(nodeId);

  // This is the function that "traverse()" will call. Return this function,
  // which will assign it to the variable traverse.
  return function () {
    node.innerHTML += 'test';
  };

// Execute the function with the id of the node to cache, i.e. output
}('output'));
```